# How to make condition inside array map loop next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

[End results UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzPEr.jpg)

So I have this data

var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

I want to check if array index is multiple of 5, so everytime the loop is on index 0,5,10 and so on, it will print this html `<div class="slide-item"><div>{data}</div></div>` but when its not in index 0,5,10 and so on (means its on 1,2,3,4,6,7,8 and so on) it will print

```
 <div class="slide-item"><div>{data 1}</div><div>{data 2}</div></div><div class="slide-item"><div>{data 3}</div><div>{data 4}</div></div>
```

so basically the end result UI is like the image attached.

My first approach is like this

```
{arr.map((res, index) => {return ({index % 5 === 0 ? (<div className="slide-item"><div>{res}</div></div>): (<div class="slide-item"><div>{data 1}</div><div>{data 2}</div></div>)}
```

i am not really sure how to do it, if theres anyone out there that can help it would be really appreciate!

Comment: Whenever you ask a question and you have an approach you should explain how your solution differs from what you actually want to achieve. (What you solution does wrong).

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to check condition based on `res` because index always start from 0

try this

```
{
    arr.map((res, index) => {
        return ( res % 5 === 0 
            ? <div className="slide-item"><div>{res}</div></div>
            : <div>
                 <div class="slide-item"><div>{data 1}</div>
                 <div>{data 2}</div></div>
              </div>
         )       
     })
}
```

Comment: This won’t - at least to my understanding of the question and the desired output - not produce the correct result. First of all the OP is talking about the index and not the value of at the index for the condition. And if you merge elements you need to skip some elements.

Answer (score 0):

`map` is not the correct function for that. The purpose of `map` is to create a new array with the same number of elements as the input elements. You however want to merge elements.

You could create some kind of hacky solution using `map`, but that's IMHO a bad idea.

I don't use react, so I can't give a react based solution. But you would need to preprocess the data (maybe a computed property).

And the preprocessing would look something like:

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
var groupedArray = []

for( let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  if( i%5 == 0 ) {
    groupedArray.push(arr[i])
  } else {
    // TODO either here or before the loop,
    // you need to make sure that i+1 exists
    groupedArray.push([arr[i], arr[i+1]])
    i+=1
  }
}

console.dir(groupedArray)
```

And use that data to create your elements. Maybe you can use the loop directly when you create your elements, but as I said I don't use react.

Depending on what you want to do you don't even need JavaScript for that, and can be done using CSS.

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  height: 110px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;

}

.list div {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  width: 90px;
  height: 50px;
}

.list div:nth-child(5n+1) {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi @t.niese thanks, I will try to use the code and get back

Comment: Hi! thanks your answer is helped me to achive the UI elements. Thank you so much!